# Issue with Redis CLuster "MovedDataException"

Tags: java, redis

I have a Redis cluster setup and working.

a specific call is returning this error:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisMovedDataException: MOVED 12867 127.0.0.1:7002
```

any ideas folks ?

a

I cant work it out.. i see connections being accepted into the cluster and Redis reports the cluster is ok.

Comment: Please add the code of how you're connection and the code that's generating the error. Also add a bit more detailed error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The node you are connecting to does not contain the key of the command to be executed or is not the master node containing the key.

The solution is to execute the command to the proper node which is `127.0.0.1:7002`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... when i try that i get the same error:  redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisMovedDataException: MOVED 12867 127.0.0.1:7002